# Python error: path is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, shutil, os.path

```py
import sys
import os
import shutil


def main(argv):
    if len(argv) < 3:
        print("To few arguments")
        return 1
    dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    latencyMonitorDir = argv[1]
    feedManagerDir = argv[2]

    if not os.path.exists(dir + r"\Data"):
        os.makedirs(dir + r"\Data")
    if not os.path.exists(dir + r"\Data\Result"):
        os.makedirs(dir + r"\Data\Result")

    scriptCommand = "\"" + dir + "\\script.py\" " + latencyMonitorDir
    os.system(scriptCommand)
    if not os.path.isfile("\"" + dir + "\\Data\\BoostedFeedManager.exe\""):
        shutil.copy(feedManagerDir + r"\BoostedFeedManager.exe", dir + "\Data")

    scriptCommand = "\"" + dir + "\\Data\\BoostedFeedManager.exe\" " + "\"" + dir + "\\Data\\configInstruments.json\""
    print("debug")
    print(scriptCommand)
    os.system(scriptCommand)  # Error
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

It makes error:

```
path is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This error emerges when I don't add quotes to path, but I'm doing it. Place of error is marked by commend "#Error".

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

*Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same limitations. Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in the environment of the executed command.*

Because if the error, the path probably doesnt exist, or it not a command/program. Try with `os.path.exist(scriptCommand)` if it exist.

Comment: in particular, you should check that the line 'shutil.copy(feedManagerDir + r"\BoostedFeedManager.exe", dir + "\Data")' is finding something

Answer (score 0):

using subprocess.getoutput('cmd')

Comment: Why do you think `subprocess.getoutput('cmd')` can solve the listed problem?